# Recover disk in NORMAL redundancy

Tags: recovery, oracle-asm

As we know NORMAL redundancy means 2 copies of each block.

I have created diskgroup:

```
CREATE DISKGROUP FG NORMAL REDUNDANCY
  FAILGROUP controller1 DISK
    'ORCL:DISK3' NAME disk3
  FAILGROUP controller2 DISK
    'ORCL:DISK4' NAME disk4;
```

I have cleared small number of blocks for the first time.

```
dd bs=1024 count=200 if=/dev/zero  of=/dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK3
```

I have corrupted header. And I was able to repair it by kfed repair, because second copy of header (located in aus=0 bs=256) was available.

```
kfed repair /dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK3  ausz=4194304
```

And it have been repaired.

But when I've corrupted the whole disk (disk size is 1GB)

```
dd bs=1M count=1024 if=/dev/zero  of=/dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK3
```

I was not able to recover disk with kfed

```
[oracle@node1 ~]$ kfed repair /dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK3  ausz=4194304
KFED-00320: Invalid block num1 = [0], num2 = [1], error = [endian_kfbh]
```

Can't I rescue disk when I have NORMAL redundancy diskgroup where other disks are healthy?

Answer (score 1):

`kfed` is only used to access asm disk headers and metadata - it won't help you in case of a full disk corruption.

You should take the bad disk offline and recover the disk group using the remaining good disk.

Regards,
Jony

Comment: Can you tell me by what tool can I recover disk using remaining good disk?

Comment: I think an only solution is this:    SQL> alter diskgroup fg drop disk disk3 force;

Diskgroup altered.

SQL>  alter diskgroup fg add disk 'ORCL:DISK3' name disk3;

Diskgroup altered.

Comment: Yes, once you add a replacement disk, asm will auto rebalance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

SQL> alter diskgroup fg drop disk disk3 force;

Diskgroup altered.

SQL>  alter diskgroup fg add disk 'ORCL:DISK3' name disk3;

Diskgroup altered.